# How can we open 2 oracle applications at the same time on the same browser?

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a requirement to open 2 oracle apex applications at the same time in the same browser.
Currently if I open the 2nd application, the existing (1st) application is overriden.

How can I see both the applications open at the same time, in 2 windows or tabs ?

Regards,
Abha

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the "Session Sharing" attribute of the authentication scheme in both apps. If it is set to "Workspace Sharing" then it should allow you to run multiple apps. After setting this attribute I did a quick test with 2 apps open in different tabs and I had no problem navigation through both apps and switching between them.